# Custom paging sorting and searching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, model-view-controller, webgrid

I was trying to find one good working example of a webgrid in MVC 5 with custom paging sorting and searching with multiple text boxes.

Can we use bootstrap them with web grid and paging?

```
@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize, defaultSort: "Name", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");
    grid.Bind(Model.Customer, autoSortAndPage: false, rowCount: Model.TotalRows);    

    @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" }, // id for ajaxUpdateContainerId parameter
                  fillEmptyRows: false,
                  tableStyle: "table table-striped table-hover",
                  alternatingRowStyle: "alternate-row",
                  headerStyle: "grid-header",
                  footerStyle: "table-responsive",
            numericLinksCount: 15,            
        columns: new[] {
        grid.Column("CustID",header: "ID", canSort: false, style:"width:10%"),
        grid.Column("Name",header: string.Format("Name {0}", grid.SortColumn == "Name" ? grid.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "⇈" : "⇊" : ""), style:"width:20%", format: @<text>@item.GetSelectLink(item.Name)</text>),
        grid.Column("Address",style:"width:400px"),
        grid.Column("ContactNo",header: "Contact No", style:"width:20%")
        }
                )
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pull-right">
            (@Model.ResultCount)
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left">

            @grid.PagerList(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                          paginationStyle: "pagination pagination-sm"
        )
        </div>
    </div>
  }
```

In this example I used pagerList and autoSortPage is false, but still it displays webgrid paging along with the custom pager.

Comment: Use the WebGrid.Table method instead of the GetHtml method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid.table(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: http://2freeclear.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/mvc-webgrid-pagination-and-sorting-with-entity-framework/

Comment: Awesome thank you so much, i did this with html knockout and web api.